# Creating JMS message using activemq and eclipse and automated with ANT?

Tags: eclipse, jms, activemq-classic

I am very novice in Java programming but In my course have to do JMS work. But I don't know how to do. and can anyone help me by sending the very clear step by step process for creating the publisher/subscriber model using activemq and eclipse? how to integrate these two and I also have to make it automated using ant but i don't know how to do.

Comment: Please try yourself first using the internet as a refernce. Then come here if you find any spcific problems.

Comment: Please add more specific questions and do something in advance. Asking for a solution of a task in your course without doing anything might not motivate anybody to give you an answer.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get them by simply google "Getting started with ActiveMQ" So alwayts try to google first and then ask here.
Anyway ActiveMQ is a messaging service. These [1](http://techdiary.bitourea.com/2008/06/activemq-510-tutorial.html) , [2](http://www.javablogging.com/simple-guide-to-java-message-service-jms-using-activemq/) , [3](http://java-diaries.blogspot.com/2011/03/get-started-with-spring-jms-using.html) are very clear tutorials.By using them You can build a simple messaging service either it use queue or topic.
But I strongly suggest you to follow [ActiveMQ guide](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/index.html) for help in your case.
Now You also want to setup eclipse and ant(as i am unable to understand why you need ant) then [follow this step by step tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheAnt/article.html).
[This may be a better tutorial among all](http://thecrumb.com/thecrumb/2008/10/14/configuring-eclipse-to-use-command-line-ant/)
Now You can find a step by step configurtation of activemq with eclipse [here](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html)